# Ajuda com array e map

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho este código, gostaria de puxar todos elementos selecionados e jogalos em um array usando map, oque estou errando? pois nao retorna nada;

```
$('#gerar').on('click',()=>{
    var selecionados = document.querySelectorAll('.select')
    var res = []
    selecionados.map(function(el){
        res.push(el)
    })
    console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: Tem como colocar o código html? Tenta usar a função normal ao invés de função de seta.

Comment: `map` serve para mapear, não para percorrer um *array*, embora como *efeito colateral* acaba percorrendo-o. Por que não faz apenas `res = [...selecionados]`, clonando o "*array*" original?

Comment: Raul, se você pegar um lista e percorrer com map para adicionar tudo em outra lista, você terá apenas duas listas iguais.

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Usando atribuição via [desestruturação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao), um novo mecanismo do ES6, tenta o seguinte:**

```js
$('#gerar').on('click', () => {
  //O segredo está aqui: (...)
  var selecionados = [...document.querySelectorAll('.select')];

  var res = []

  selecionados.map(function(el) {
    res.push(el)
  })

  console.log(res)

  //Podes usar o seguinte também:
  //Conforme:
  //https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList
  var list = document.querySelectorAll('.select');

  let myArry = [];

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, function(item) {
    myArry.push(item);
  });

  console.log(myArry);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">Texto 1 </div>
<div class="select">Texto 2 </div>
<div class="select">Texto 3 </div>
<div class="select">Texto 4 </div>

<button id="gerar">Teste </button>
```

Comment: Eu deixei meu -1 porque considero isso um uso incorreto do `map` e, portanto, ao meu ver, é gambiarra. Se o intuito é jogar todos os elementos de um *array* para outro, isso não é mapeamento; basta clonar o *array* original.